# How to trace erc20 testnet deposit with web3.JS

Tags: web3js, infura

I am using ropsten testnet, I wish to detect deposit of an erc-20 token. I am using infura and use method of `eth_getBlockByNumber` to get all the transactions and check whether the `to` field match an address in my database. However, when I transfer token, the `to` will show the token as the address. How can I get the actual `to` and `amount transfered` when detecting deposit?

Comment: erc20 token has events ... so a transfer function will emit an event and you need to trace the event "Transfer" of the specific Erc20Contract (which include to- from- and amount..). That is much better and easier than checking all transactions

Answer (score 1):

With web3.js v1.x, you can use this:

```
const PARTIAL_ABI = [{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
        {"indexed": true , "name": "from" , "type": "address"},
        {"indexed": true , "name": "to"   , "type": "address"},
        {"indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256"},
    ],
    "name": "Transfer",
    "type": "event",
}];

async function getTransferEvents(tokenAddress, fromBlock, toBlock) {
    const token = new web3.eth.Contract(PARTIAL_ABI, tokenAddress);
    return await token.getPastEvents("Transfer", {fromBlock: fromBlock, toBlock: toBlock});
}
```